# Remember Me while logging in with Facebook in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5, remember-me

I have my application built in laravel 5.2. I have the remember me token functionality in the app. It works fine for the normal login, But I wanted to have it for the facebook users also. I mean when the user tries to login to their account using facebook, I want to save remember me at that time too. Can anyone have the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Store user preference in cookie and check it on login page .